# Панели перекрывают друг друга в java

Tags: java, swing

Разбираюсь с отображением кнопок `GridBagLayout`, для примера взял типа калькулятор, кнопки на одной панели, поле ввода цифр на другой, и все это соединяется с фреймом. Но проблема в том что только одно отображается (то что последним добавляется). В других `Layout` все норм, таким методом добавляется и отображается, а вот тут `GridBagLayout` как то не выходит отобразить две панели одновременно, вот весь код:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GridBagLayoutTutorial {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel paneldig = new JPanel();
    JPanel paneldisp = new JPanel();
    JTextField display = new JTextField(30);


    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


    JButton _1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton _2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton _3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton _4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton _5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton _6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton _7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton _8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton _9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton _0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton pnt = new JButton(".");
    JButton eqe = new JButton("=");
    JButton plus = new JButton("+");
    JButton minus = new JButton("-");
    JButton mult = new JButton("*");
    JButton div = new JButton("/");

    public GridBagLayoutTutorial()
    {
        paneldig.setLayout(gbl);        
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;   
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        paneldig.add(_1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        paneldig.add(_2, gbc);

        //gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        //gbc.gridheight= 4;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        paneldig.add(_3, gbc);//.........123

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        paneldig.add(_4, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        paneldig.add(_5, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        paneldig.add(_6, gbc);//.........456
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        paneldig.add(_7, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        paneldig.add(_8, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        paneldig.add(_9, gbc);//.........789

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        paneldig.add(_0, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        paneldig.add(pnt, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        paneldig.add(eqe, gbc);//.........0_point_eque

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        paneldig.add(plus, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        paneldig.add(minus, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        paneldig.add(mult, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        paneldig.add(div, gbc);


        paneldisp.add(display);


        frame.add(paneldig);
        frame.add(paneldisp);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridBagLayoutTutorial add = new GridBagLayoutTutorial();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в `GridBagLayout`, а в том, как вы добавляете две панели на `JFrame`. Layout manager'ом в контентной панели `JFrame` является `BorderLayout`, который, если явно не указать, добавляет новый компонент, как центральный. Поэтому `frame.add(paneldisp);` затирает работу предыдущего вызова, и `BorderLayout` перестает управлять размерами панели.

Можете сделать так:

```
frame.add(paneldig, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(paneldisp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

`JFrame` для удобства переопределяет `add`, `remove` и `setLayout`, передавая вызов `contentPane`, но лучше явно создать новую общую панель, и установить ее во фрейм:

```
JPanel content = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
content.add( paneldisp, BorderLayout.NORTH );
content.add( paneldig, BorderLayout.CENTER );

frame.setContentPane( content );
```

- [Java Turtorials: Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам посоветовал так , если вам нужно расположить много кнопок в определенном порядке , то используйте абсолютное позицинирование.

```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);


    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("BTN");
    btnAdd.setBounds( 50,350,140,30 );
    panel.add( btnAdd );
```

Тут вы можете указать любую позицию для своей кнопки , работает отлично .